# Inserting Dates into Rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` whose index consist of Datetimes of each day in January for the years 1997 through 2011:

```
In [164]: df
Out[164]: 
             Tavg
1997-01-01  20.48
1997-01-02  37.49
...           ...
1997-01-31  37.49
1998-01-01  52.07
...           ...
2011-01-30  35.51
2011-01-31  29.03
```

From another DataFrame, I'd like to insert rows to `df` corresponding to Dec 31 of the previous year for each year; i.e., rows with index

```
In [166]: prev_dates = pd.date_range('1996-12-31', '2010-12-31', freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))

In [167]: prev_dates
Out[167]: 
DatetimeIndex(['1996-12-31', '1997-12-31', '1998-12-31', '1999-12-31',
               '2000-12-31', '2001-12-31', '2002-12-31', '2003-12-31',
               '2004-12-31', '2005-12-31', '2006-12-31', '2007-12-31',
               '2008-12-31', '2009-12-31', '2010-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: kwds={'years': 1}>')
```

After inserting the values from these rows, I'd like the new `df` to look like

```
             Tavg
1996-12-31  <new value>
1997-01-01  20.48
1997-01-02  37.49
...           ...
1997-01-31  37.49
1997-12-31  <new value>
1998-01-01  52.07
...           ...
2011-01-30  35.51
2011-01-31  29.03
```

but I can't seem to find the right methods to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reindex` with `union`

```
df.reindex(prev_dates.union(df.index))
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea you could do this.  Thanks.